# Sorting list of strings using linq with custom sort

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of strings in an order that is pertinent to a sequence used in common revision history sequences. Some customers start with "-", or "New", or a few other specific codes, and I can use LINQ to define a custom sort order. However, after a drawing has been revised from Rev A all the way through Rev Z, it becomes Rev AA through Rev AZ, then Rev BA through BZ and so forth.  How can I sort the following list using LINQ?

I have this as an example block of code:

```
List<string> revList = new List<string>  { "A", "NC", "New", "AB", "PD", "PD1", 
                                          "PD2", "B", "-", "*", "BB", "NA" };
revList = revList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "pd").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "nc").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "na").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "new").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "pd1").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "pd2").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "-").
                  ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "*").
                  ThenBy(i => i).ToList();

foreach (string rev in revList)
  Console.WriteLine(rev);
```

This produces output as:

```
PD
NC
NA
NEW
PD1
PD2
-
*
A
AB
B
B
```

I would like to produce:

```
PD
NC
NA
NEW
PD1
PD2
-
*
A
B
AB
BB
```

Comment: Sort by `Length` first, e.g.  insert `ThenBy(i => i.Length).` before `ThenBy(i => i)`

Comment: Ivan, you win. I wish I could vote for your answer since it was first, but it was a comment. Thank You.

Comment: Why did `PD` come before `NC` is the desired results?

Comment: @JonathanWood Because of the first rule itself!

Comment: @JonathanWood Obscure details that are really only relevant to our specific numbering requirements.  The pertinent part was that I could create a specific sequence of order using LINQ, but I couldn't figure out how to get the subsequent sequence to work in a non alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code worked for me.

```
 var revList = new List<string>  { "A", "NC", "New", "AB", "PD", "PD1",
                                      "PD2", "B", "-", "*", "BB", "NA" };

        revList = revList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "pd").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "nc").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "na").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "new").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "pd1").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "pd2").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "-").
                          ThenByDescending(i => i.ToLower() == "*").
                          ThenBy(i => i.Length).ToList();

        foreach (string rev in revList)
            Console.WriteLine(rev);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks, Sameer! I cant believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom object like this:

```
class Revision
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    public Revision(string Name, int Rank)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Rank = Rank;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a list of these objects.

Something like:

```
List<Revision> revisions = new List<Revision>();
revision.Add(new Revision("PD",1));
revision.Add(new Revision("NC",2));
```

Now when you can sort by the rank using LINQ instead of trying to parse the names.

It may be a pain to set up the object initially since you may need to go out to ZZ, but this would give you complete control over the order.

p.s. - I didn't test this code.